# cpack and install(CODE ...) - CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX vs CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

Tags: cmake, cpack

as a "post-install hook" I need to execute an install command like

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND some_command ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/some_folder"))
```

which creates a file in `some_folder` based on the files which were previously installed into `some_folder` (it compiles an index/cache of those files).

This works fine for the install target, however as soon as using cpack `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` is not the correct location anymore.

Is there a variable like ${CMAKE_CURRENT_INSTALL_PREFIX} that always points towards the current installation directory, regardless of wether the default install target or cpack is used and can be used for this purpose?

The only alternative I see is to try to execute the command at an earlier stage on the original files, create a temporary file and install the temporary file. Unfortunately this is much more error prone, as `some_command` should be run on the "final" files after installation (in order to create a valid cache)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer turns out to be extremely simple (kudos to Nils Gladitz from IRC):

Escaping the variable `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` with a backslash delays its expansion until install time at which it holds the correct value also for installs via CPack:

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND some_command \${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/some_folder"))
```