# CMake install(CODE) finding DESTINATION artifacts

Tags: cmake

After installing some build artifacts:

```
install(TARGETS linktest
    DESTINATION .
    COMPONENT linkTest)
```

I want to do some post-processing using `install(CODE)` on those artifacts, along the lines of:

```
install(CODE "
  execute_process(COMMAND sh -c \"
    echo Do stuff in `pwd`
    exit 0
  \")
" COMPONENT linkTest)
```

The default working directory of `install(CODE)` seems to be the build directory corresponding to the current `CMakeLists.txt` directory of the source, e.g. when I run `cpack` in verbose mode:

```
CPack Verbose: Installing: /Users/jake/devel/linktest.build/_CPack_Packages/Darwin/ZIP/LinkTest-0.1.1-Darwin/./liblinktest.dylib
Do stuff in /Users/jake/devel/linktest.build
```

How can I find the correct directory to pass to `WORKING_DIRECTORY` so the script runs from the directory specified by `DESTINATION .` in the `install(TARGETS)` command?

Comment: Just use [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) variable: `WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`.

Comment: Seems it needs to be `\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` to delay expansion but that works.  Feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: Hm, `install(CODE)` accepts string as a code, no needs to delay expansions of variables which are already defined.

Comment: When CPack runs the value will be different than at CMake generation time.

Answer (score 3):

Using [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) with delayed expansion works:

```
install(CODE "
  execute_process(COMMAND sh -c \"
    echo Do stuff in `pwd`
    exit 0
  \"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY \${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
" COMPONENT linkTest)
```

We have to use `\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` instead of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` so it will be evaluated when CPack runs instead of at config generation time, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487133/1464861).

New output:

```
CPack Verbose: Installing: /Users/jake/devel/linktest.build/_CPack_Packages/Darwin/ZIP/LinkTest-0.1.1-Darwin/./liblinktest.dylib
Do stuff in /Users/jake/devel/linktest.build/_CPack_Packages/Darwin/ZIP/LinkTest-0.1.1-Darwin
```