# Is it possible to determine whether CMake install(CODE) is called from the "install" or "package" stage?

Tags: cmake, cpack, windeployqt

I'm using CMake v3.21.0 to invoke Qt's [windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) during the install stage by the means of the [install(CODE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#code) command as follows:

```
install(
    CODE "
    execute_process(
      COMMAND \"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" -E
        env PATH=\"${windeployqt_ROOT_DIR}\"
        \"${windeployqt_EXECUTABLE}\"
        # TODO(2021-08-25 by wolters): This is a different path when CPack is`
        # used. How to check for this case and obtain the correct output path?
        --dir \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${args_INSTALL_SUFFIX}\"
        --no-quick-import
        --no-system-d3d-compiler
        --no-virtualkeyboard
        --no-compiler-runtime
        --no-webkit2
        --no-angle
        --no-opengl-sw
        --verbose 0
        \"\$<TARGET_FILE:${args_TARGET}>\"
    )
    "
    COMPONENT runtime
  )
```

This works fine if installing the project:

```
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo --target install
```

But when creating a CPack package the files created by `windeployqt` are **not** part of the package (ZIP in this case):

```
cpack -G ZIP -C RelWithDebInfo -D CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL="runtime"
```

I know that the issue is the usage of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` in the `CODE`.

1. For the `install` target this is correct.
2. For the `package` target this is not correct. Instead the build directory for the **current** CPack generator should be used, e.g. `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_CPack_Packages/win64/ZIP/${CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME}`.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to differentiate between `install` and `package` target in the `CODE` section? (pseudo-code: `if(CMAKE_IS_PACKAGING)`)
2. If there is a way: Is it possible to obtain or dynamically build the directory path to the actual CPack temporary "install" directory?

If both problems can be solved the files generated by `windeployqt` should be part of the packages generated by CPack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` *should not* be expanded in the CMakeLists.txt, as you are doing. Its actual value at invocation time is available inside the `install(CODE)` fragments.

Consider the following snippet:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test NONE)

install(CODE [[message(STATUS "HERE: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")]])
```

Note that `[[ ... ]]` escapes variable expansions (you could also use backslashes). Now if you configure this project with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/install`, you'll see the message print as you expect.

```
$ cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/install
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
$ cmake --build build/ --target install
[0/1] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- HERE: /tmp/install
```

If you now run the install script again *without reconfiguring or rebuilding*, it will still work:

```
$ cmake --install build/ --prefix /tmp/other-prefix
-- Install configuration: ""
-- HERE: /tmp/other-prefix
```

This is how CPack runs your install rules. It does *not* use the configuration-time value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. It expects your project to be relocatable (i.e. bug-free).

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understand your point here. I understand the behavior described by you regarding the "install" step. But my issue isn't the install step, but the "package" step. CPack doesn't rely on the installation directory but creates a separate (temporary) directory in the build directory that is used for the packaging (`${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_CPack_Packages`).  I've **assumed** that CPack modifies `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` in a way that you described but that isn't the case as described in my OP. `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` != the directory CPack uses for packaging.

Comment: In the mean time I found https://stackoverflow.com/q/48477588/891439. i think this is what you are refererring to as "variable expansion"? I wasn't aware of this future until now. One backslash makes a **huge** difference: The package is properly created when using `\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` in the `install(CODE)` command. Thank you for pointing to the right direction!

Comment: @FlorianWolters - happy to help! Is there an adjustment I could make to my answer to improve it / have it accepted?